# Geoserver "too many clients already" error

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql

I'm creating an application to display some data with geoserver and postgres database.
My application is working fine when I display 5-6 layers of data one by one, after that, the next layers I try to display are not displayed correctly, only a few tiles are on the screen. When I look up the Geoserver database I have error message

> FATAL: sorry too many clients already connected

[image]

Comment: two suggestions:

-1- use caching, if applicable, to reduce load on DBMS
-2- go the configuration of the postgis store and increase the max number of connections in the pool which is 10 by default.

Answer (score 2):

If I'm reading the error message correctly ("désolé, top de clients son deja connectés"), Postgresql itself is complaining about the too many connections from GeoServer.
You should check how many connections your server is allowing, and either increase it, or reduce the number of connections in your store configuration so that it won't go above.

Just to make sure, you have a single postgresql data store in your configuration, and are getting many layers out of it, and not one store per layer, right?

Comment: I thanks too answer, i just increase the parameter max_connection in postgresSQL , i restart the services, but nothing happen, my problem is style there. 
I have one database, with multiple layer  out of it with geoserver yes

Comment: Hum... I don't have a quick solution then... are you using a recent version of GeoServer? If not try upgrading.